# Replace all values in one column to 1

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep, replace

I have multiple text files containing 12 lines and 3 columns.

Example:

```
2       6    0.74  
42      6    0.58  
80      6    0  
112     6    0.24  
132     6    1  
216     6    0.7  
342     6    0  
390     6    0.21  
432     6    0.56  
466     6    0.75  
524     6    0.6  
646     6    0.9
```

I want to set all the values of the third column to 1 in all lines.

The output should look like this :

```
2    6   1  
42   6   1  
80   6   1  
112  6   1  
132  6   1  
216  6   1  
342  6   1  
390  6   1  
432  6   1  
466  6   1  
524  6   1  
646  6   1
```

Does anyone know a command that can solve this problem?

Answer (score 17):

```
awk '{print $1, $2, "1"}' inputfile
```

Comment: This command prints out the first line in the textfile corrrectly in terminal, but does not make changes in the file...

Comment: redirect the output to another file `awk '{print $1, $2, "1"}' inputfile > newfile`

Comment: Thanks! It works but only writes out the first line, column 1, 2 and 3. I would like to write out all 12 lines in the same manner :)

Answer (score 12):

try

## awk

```
 awk '{$3=1 ; print ;}' oldfile > newfile
```

- `$3 = 1` will set third field to 1

## sed (here GNU or busybox `sed` with its `-i` option for in-place editing)

```
sed -i 's/[0-9.]*$/1/' file
```

- `[0-9.]*$` is a sequence from `0` to `9` and `.` up to the end of line.

## sed (golfed 4 bytes)

```
sed -i 's/[^ ]*$/1/' file
```

- `[^ ]*$` any char other than space, until end of line.

Comment: Let's codegolf: `sed 's/[^ ]*$/1/'` :->

Comment: Thank you so much! :) The awk  seems to work, except for the first line:      2 6 1 6 1                                                                                                           
80 6 1  
112 6 1                                  
132 6 1  
216 6 1  
342 6 1  
390 6 1  
432 6 1  
466 6 1  
524 6 1  
646 6 1  
    The first line prints the 2nd and 3rd value twice?

Comment: @user203269  awk version works fine for me (albeit with a formating issue)

Comment: `awk` golfed: `awk \$3=1` (POSIX but would not work with the awk from the 70s as found in /bin on Solaris)

Comment: that `awk` solution is really cool....can you explain pls

Comment: sed -i 's/[0-9.]*$/1/' File.txt  gives this error:
sed: 1: "File.txt": invalid command code L

Comment: @user203269, on BSDs, use `-i ''` instead of `-i`

Comment: i '' : It does not give the error , but it does not make any changes to the textfile...

Answer (score 5):

The lines in your expected output seem to end in two space characters and have fields separated by one tab and one space character.

If that's indeed what you want, then you'd need:

```
awk -v 'OFS=\t ' '$3="1  "' < infile > outfile
```

Or with `sed`:

```
tab=$(printf '\t')
sed "
  s/[[:blank:]]\{1,\}/$tab /g
  s/[^[:blank:]]\{1,\}[[:blank:]]*$/1  /
  s/^[[:blank:]]*//" < infile > outfile
```

Comment: Why the spaces after 1?

Comment: @123, like I said, in the OP's expected output, every line ends in two space characters.

Comment: Misread thought you said fields were separated by two space and a tab. my bad.

Comment: Hi Stephane, This awk does the first three values correctly, then it deletes column1 line 2 and continues without making changes..

Comment: @user203269, convert your file from MS-DOS to Unix first.

Comment: Thank you Stephane! How do I do that? :)

Answer (score 3):

Simply with GNU `sed`, using `-i` to replace text directly in the file:

```
sed -i 's:\(.*\s\)\(.*\s\)\(.*\):\1\21:g' textfile
```

The columns are matched by regex groups in the parenthesis, reusing them with `\1` and `\2` and then using a "1" to replace the last group.

In this use case, the solution proposed using `awk` is nice and short as well.

Answer (score 2):

this will do the job:

```
cat textfiles | cut -d' ' -f-2 | sed 's/$/ 1/'
```

Comment: cat file.txt | cut -d' ' -f-2 | sed 's/$/ 1/'
646     6 0.5 1
prints out one line (the last line) in the terminal, but does not change the file.txt...

Answer (score -1):

```
cat filename | awk -F ' ' '{$3=1; print $0}' > filename
```

Comment: Could you please edit your post to include more context as to why you feel this is the solution?